# The start date of the Reserved Instance (Amazon AWS) term from boto python library

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

This seems like a super basic question because I have been using the boto library to access amazon aws api from python for a long time now and for some reason I can not find the call to get the start date of the reserved instance.

You can get the start date from the direct api call as stated here under the Output section.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeReservedInstances.html

However from the boto library there is no information returned that gives  you the reservation start date

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.reservedinstance.ReservedInstance

Any help would be appreciated as I have been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours trying to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReservedInstance` object returned by boto should have a `start` attribute that contains the same value returned as the `start_date` by the EC2 CLI tool.

Comment: Hmmm, I will give that a try but in the documentation that is not stated under the ReservedInstance object.

Comment: You're right.  The docs are incomplete.  I'll create an issue on github and get those updated.  Thanks for pointing that out.